# $\tanh (x+y)=\tanh (z)\rightarrow x+y=z?$

Tags: trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

Why is this true? I just read this in a relativity theory textbook without any proof. Is that really that obvious?

Comment: No, it's false. For example, $2\tanh(1)\approx1.523$ and $\tanh(2)\approx0.964$.

Comment: Glad to read that. Thx

Comment: Were it true, it would mean that $\tanh$ is a linear function.

Comment: Such a book is unlikely to make this kind of error. Double check what you read.

Comment: Good hint. You were right. I edited the equation

Comment: Yes, it's obvious: $\tanh$ is strictly increasing, hence injective.

Comment: Good explanation. Thank you

Comment: Silently changing the problem statement after the fact isn't the best thing to do.

Comment: Silently? See the comments. I said that I edited the equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\tanh(x)=\operatorname{sech}^2(x)\gt0
$$
So $\tanh(x)$ is strictly increasing, hence injective.

Answer (score 1):

Using the definition and a simple calculation shows

$\tanh(a)=\tanh(b)$  iff $e^{a-b}=e^{b-a}$  iff $a=b$